# Any Hadoop AWS S3 Credential Provider class to handle both temp session token and role arn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop

I have a Spark on Hadoop Application that writes to AWS S3.
The problem is I am using `AssumedRoleCredentialProvider` as a credential provider because I have role_arn

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn","arn:aws:iam::321849:role/some_role")
```

But I also have a session token to be used:

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key','xxxx')
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key','xxxx')
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.session.token','xxxx')
```

As I am not providing `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` as a credential provider, I am hitting below even though I have a valid session token with me:

```
The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId;
```

Any pointers on how to solve having talked on both the scenarios?

Comment: Well, which on is it? Do you have access tokens (access+secret+session) or do you want to assume a role and use its credentials? Or is the problem that you want to start with the access tokens to then assume the role?

Comment: @luk2302 last part of your question

Comment: How are the original access tokens provided? Can't you assume the target role outside of spark and then pass the returned access tokens from the assumed role into the application? What you can always do is write your own credentials provider, package it, distribute it to the spark app and then reference it within the fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider config. But that is a very verbose solution to the problem. That being said I am not familiar enough with the different credential providers to know how they may interact in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

`AssumedRoleCredentialProvider` needs full credentials as it
talks to STS to get credentials for the given role.

AFAIK you can't talk to STS with session creds.

but the hadoop utility tool cloudstore can generate a set of session keys and give you the values in the forms of hadoop xml, spark defaults and env vars for bash and fish. I use it when I need to use my creds on a remote cluster.

https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/blob/trunk/src/main/site/sessionkey.md